# How to print logs in jsonformat with metadata field in jbpm/wildfly?

Tags: java, logging, wildfly, jbpm

I am using jbpm 7.37 standard edition, with  WildFly Full 14.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 6.0.2.Final).
I am using logger class(org.slf4j.LoggerFactory,org.slf4j.Logger) to print the logs.
I have enabled custom REST endpoints.I am using Jersey REST api.
I am making custom jar fil where I have written custom code (custom REST APIs) and deploying this jar file inside kie-server.war file.
I want to print logs in json format for my custom class.
Like below :

```
{"timestamp":"2021-03-04T05:27:07.063Z",
"service":"demo",
"level":"error/info",
"message":"Errormessage/Info message",
"metadata":{"requestId":"somerequestid","sessionId":"somesif"}
}
```

However i am able to print logs in json format with the below command :

```
sudo bash jboss-cli.sh -c "/subsystem=logging/json-formatter=json:com.demo.add(exception-output-type=formatted, pretty-print=true, meta-data={service=demo})"
```

But this gives me output like below :

```
{"timestamp":"2021-03-04T05:27:07.063Z",
"service":"demo",
"level":"error/info",
"message":"Errormessage/Info message",
}
```

Not able to print the **"metadata":{"requestId":"somerequestid","sessionId":"somesrequestid"}**

The fields requestId and sessionId are having runtime values which i have to get from the http request.
From @HeaderParam("requestId"),@HeaderParam("sessionId") and needs to append with each and every response.

When i append this values in my response it shows inside the "message" field as follow.

```
{"timestamp":"2021-03-04T05:27:07.063Z",
"service":"demo",
"level":"error/info",
"message":"data{"requestId":"somerequestId","sessionId":"somesessionId"}",
}
```

How do i print the values for requestId and sessionId for each and every request
as "metadata":{"requestId":"somerequestid","sessionId":"somesid"} ?

Comment: Have you tried setting MDC values for that?

Comment: How can i set this MDC? Is there any example ?

Comment: Since you're using slf4j before you're log message you'd just add something like `MDC.put("requestid", getRequestId());` Do the same for session and clear it when after the `logger.xxx`.

Comment: But i want to print like this "metadata":{"requestId":"somerequestid","sessionId":"somesif"}

Comment: Thanks James .I am able to print sessionid and requestid but it print like "mdc":{"requestId":"somerequestid","sessionId":"somesif"}.but i want  to print like "metadata":{"requestId":"somerequestid","sessionId":"somesif"} .Any suggestion please.

Comment: Metadata cannot handle runtime data unfortunately. MDC is the only way I can think of to make that work.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins do you know how we can separate logs for ERROR and INFO in different file? where we have to configure? or any command ? default location is /JBOSSHOME/standalone/logs/server.log file where all logs are stored but i want to separate LEVEL.INFO in one file and LEVEL.ERROR in another file.Please help.

Comment: That's definitely possible, but kind of tough to answer in a comment. The short version is you need a combo of handlers and filters on those handlers or a custom handler.

Comment: <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="MYLOG" autoflush="true" enabled="true"><level name="ERROR"/>
<formatter><named-formatter name="json"/></formatter><file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="jbpm_info.log"/><suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/><append value="true"/></periodic-rotating-file-handler><logger category="com.abc.api" use-parent-handlers="false">
<level name="ERROR"/><handlers><handler name="MYLOG"/></handlers></logger> I did like this but it prints error logs of com.abc.api , i want to print info logs of com.abc.api in diff file too

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67915876/how-to-log-info-logs-and-error-logs-into-different-files-in-wild-fly-server   - You can visit the question here pls.