# how to log info logs and error logs into different files in WILD FLY server?

Tags: java, logging, wildfly, jbpm

I have made changed in the standalone.xml file as below :

```
 <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="MYLOG" autoflush="true" enabled="true">
    <level name="ERROR"/>
    <formatter>
        <named-formatter name="json"/>
    </formatter>
    <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="my_error.log"/>
    <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    <append value="true"/>
</periodic-rotating-file-handler>
<logger category="com.abc.api" use-parent-handlers="false">
    <level name="ERROR"/>
    <handlers>
      <handler name="MYLOG"/>
    </handlers>
</logger>
```

But this handler print ERROR logs in my_error.log for com.abc.api package.I also wanted to print the INFO logs of com.abc.api package in my_info.log file.

Can someone please help here.

Comment: What do you want to happen with WARN messages? Does you `my_info.log` file look like a similar configuration?

Comment: We can ignore WARN meassges, I want to print only INFO and ERROR message in separate file.

Comment: What i tried is , Created two handlers and assign level as info and error , and then  did as follow :<logger category="com.abc" use-parent-handlers="true"><handlers><handler name="MYLOG"/><handler name="MYINFOLOG"/></handlers></logger> , it works like error msg prints in error file and also info msgs in info file but this info file aslo prints the error msgs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `levels` filter on the handler to filter the log messages you would like to see in the handler. You can configure logging with the following CLI commands:

```
/subsystem=logging/periodic-rotating-file-handler=info-handler:add(named-formatter=json, file={relative-to=jboss.server.log.dir, path=info.log}, level=INFO, filter-spec=levels(INFO), suffix=".yyyy-MM-dd")
/subsystem=logging/periodic-rotating-file-handler=error-handler:add(named-formatter=json, file={relative-to=jboss.server.log.dir, path=error.log}, level=ERROR, suffix=".yyyy-MM-dd")
/subsystem=logging/logger=com.abc.api:add(handlers=[info-handler, error-handler])
```

Note I did not add the `use-parent-handlers=false`. This allows messages to still be logged into the `server.log` in case you need them.

Comment: This works like  a charm by adding filter-spec.Thanks.Just one last thing , is there any way we can implement of archive of this logs after a month ends.Meaning logs file should be removed to specific archive folder after a new month starts.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not currently supported in the log manager itself. If you're on a Linux based system you could use a cron job to do that though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68179420/can-we-delete-content-from-jbpm-standalone-tmp-vfs-folder-in-wildfly-14 - Do you know this ?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not. I do not know anything about JBPM.